# Dynamic Import wrong path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to load locale files based on the locale code given by Next.js. But whenever I'm trying to do a dynamic import, an error happens and the import path is wrong:

```
Unable to load translation file "index": Error: Cannot find module './index.en.json'
```

Code to import:

```js
    try {
        Object.assign(messages, await import(`@/locales/${name}.${locale}.json`))
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Unable to load translation file "${name}": ${err}`)
        error = err
    }
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/locales/*": ["locales/*"]
    }
```

next.config.js with webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias[`@/locales`] = path.resolve(__dirname, "locales")

    return config
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, I found my mistake, the file was named `index.de.json` instead of `index.en.json`. But still I want to know why the error message shows a wrong path.

Comment: "The filename is wrong" and "the path is wrong" are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this way. If it does not work please check `@/locales/` path was correctly set.

**Example:**

```
  import(`@/locales/${name}.${locale}.json`).then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
    Object.assign(messages, json)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Unable to load translation file "${name}": ${err}`)
    error = err
  });
```